# How to nest JavaScript code and pseudo-HTML elements in multiple levels?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I haven't read a rule like this, but is the following how it works?

We can write

```
return <ul>{this.state.numbers.map(a => <li>{a}</li>)}</ul>;
```

and the rule is

1. When we see the first word `return`, it is regular JS
2. When we are in regular JS mode, we are free to begin any "pseudo-HTML tag", and when it becomes `<ul>`, it is "pseudo-HTML tag mode", and we cannot have any regular JS code, unless if we begin another `{`
3. Now that we have a `{`, we are back in regular JS mode, but we can start using any `<div>` or `<li>` again, but as long as those as not "close" or have the final end tag, it will continue to be "pseudo-HTML tag mode".
4. So that's why we can have `<li>`, but then to use any JS code again, we again need to start a `{`

So maybe it can be summarized as this: we can write any regular JS code, and even `<div>` etc can be considered to be JS code, but as long as it has not closed with the final `</div>`, then we cannot have regular JS code again, unless if we start with a `{`.  And then, we can have regular JS code again, and free to begin another `<span>` or whatever.  When that `<span>` has closed with `</span>`, we can use regular JS code; but before that, if we need to use any regular JS code again, we need to begin a `{` again.

Is this how it works? Is this mentioned in any JSX docs?

Comment: They are all Javascript. What you call "pseudo-HTML tag" (or JSX) will be compiled down to regular javascript (using Babel). [reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#jsx-represents-objects)

Answer (score 0):

Actually as you mentioned this is JSX and your are not able to write plain JavaScript code inside (like if-else, for etc.).
When we convert your code your using babel it seems

```
function render() {
  return _react.default.createElement("ul", null, this.state.numbers.map(function (a) {
    return _react.default.createElement("li", null, a);
  }));
}
```

As you can see tags are **elements**. and we can say that partially yes this how it works.

you can use [Babel jsx convert](https://babeljs.io/repl/)

another usefull links about jsx. [The 6 rules of JSX: a live cheatsheet](https://frontarm.com/james-k-nelson/jsx-live-cheatsheet/)

Comment: maybe we can see it as, once there is `<div>`, we can see it as a `React.createElement()` and as long as there is no matching `</div>`, it is still inside of this `React.createElement()`, and so if you want any regular JS, you need the `{  }`